# Ошибка чтения enum-поля таблицы в сущность

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-jpa

Есть таблица `product` с полем `type VARCHAR(64)`. Для этой таблицы создал соответствующую сущность `Product`, где атрибут `type` -- enum. При попытке выбрать все записи получаю следующее исключение: *org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: столбец product0_.type не существует*.

Данные получаю с помощью дефолтного метода Spring JpaRepository

enum:

```
public enum ProductType {
    SNEAKERS,
    JACKET
}
```

Product:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product extends BaseEntity {
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "type")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ProductType type;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "product_size",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "size_id")
    )
    private List<ProductSize> sizes;
}
```

BaseEntity:

```
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
```

[image: поля таблицы]

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось, проблема была в конфигурационном файле application.properties.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).